# Polymer 2.0 Upgrade

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

We have developed our web app using polymer 0.5. We haven't upgraded it yet, there is a request for a new page creation. Question is, can we have that page alone created using polymer 2, whereas the rest of the app still runs in 0.5.

Also request to provide some pointers on login page custom element. It will be a simple user/password field.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use information in this post https://jcrowther.io/2015/06/01/upgrading-from-polymer-v0-5-v1-0/ to migrate to 1.0 and then make minor changes to run on 1.9 and finaly you can use Polymer linter avaiable in https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-linter with `--fix` option in *polymer-2-hybrid* mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that 0.5 version elements will be complatible with 2.0. There have been few changes.

Upgrading to version 1.9.1 should be ok. Without any hard problems. So you should first try this and repair some errors that might occur. Then read documentation about upgrading to Polymer 2.0. You will be using **hybrid elements**. This is important, because in Polymer 2.0 there are 2 choices of how to define elements.

If you don't have that much time playing with upgrading, or is your app simply large, then upgrading to 1.9.1 should be the best option.